# Is tslint white space rule works for imports

Tags: tslint

After adding check-module it fixed the white space issue when I ran tslint-fix
whitespace: ["check-module",etc]

Before

```
import {someone} from 'module';
```

after

```
import { someone } from 'module';
```

But still I had an issue with alias name:

Current:

```
import {default as sample, somesample } from './models/samples';
```

Expected:

```
import { default as sample, somesample } from './models/samples';
```

Will any White Space rule fixes this?

Answer (score 0):

Well this may be a bug of ts-lint, or some miss-configuration, you can try another syntax to see if works for you:

`import sample, {someone} from './models/sample'`